# My program won't update the textview from another class, it quits out every time, and I don't know why?

Tags: java, android, class, crash, display

## Top Level Activity

This activity is the one that recieves the display update from my other class, Post Activity

### The goal of these two programs is to send displays back and forth, going from one screen to the other and updating the calendar display of the main activity from the post activity class.  If anyone has any suggestions it would be really helpful!!

```
    package com.example.oife;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class TopLevelActivity extends Activity {


    public TextView mText;
    //Context context;
   // private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;

    /*public TopLevelActivity(Context context){
        this.context = context;

    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_oife);

        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

        long date = System.currentTimeMillis();

        TextView displayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayDate);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        String dateString = sdf.format(date);
        displayDate.setText(dateString);
    }



   /* @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_oife, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
        //setIntent("This is example text");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }*/

    /*private void setIntent(String text) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
    }*/

  /*  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
*/
    //call onPostClick() method when the button is clicked
    public void onPostClick (View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PostActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //call onHomeClick() method when the button is clicked
    public void onHomeClick (View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,TopLevelActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //call onMoreClick() method when the button is clicked
    public void onMoreClick(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MoreActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    public TextView getMainText(){
        return mText;
    }

    public void setMText(TextView t){


        mText.setText(t.getText());
    }

}
```

## Now here's Post Activity

This class has the update display function which should update the textview calendar in the other class

---

```
package com.example.oife;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;

public class PostActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView pDisplayDate;
    private Button pPickDate;
    private int pYear;
    private int pMonth;
    private int pDay;
    private TextView MAINText;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private TextView day;
    private TextView xyz;
    TopLevelActivity top;
    TextView d ;
    RadioGroup t;
    RadioGroup g;
    protected TopLevelActivity context;


    public PostActivity(Context context){
        this.context = (TopLevelActivity) context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);



        /** Capture our View elements */
        pDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayDate);
        pPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
        xyz = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
       top = new TopLevelActivity();
        /** Listener for click event of the button */
        pPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
        t = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.TOD);
       d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        g = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.WoW);

        MAINText = new TextView(this);
        day = new TextView(this);

        /** Get the current date */
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        pYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        pMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        pDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        /** Display the current date in the TextView */
       // updateDisplay();

    }



   public void setMainText(){

       day.setText(makeDay().getText());

        this.MAINText.setText(top.getMainText() + "/n/n" + xyz + "/n" + day + "/n" + d.getText());

    }

    private TextView makeDay(){
        TextView ToD;
        int id = t.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(id == -1) {
            ToD = null;
        }
        else{
         ToD = (TextView) findViewById(id);
        }

        /*TextView wow;

        id = g.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if (id == -1){
            wow = null;
        }
        else{
            wow = (TextView) findViewById(id);
        }
        */

        TextView d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayDate);

        String s = String.valueOf(d);
        String j;
        if (ToD.getText().equals("Morning")){
            j = "9:00";
        }
        else if(ToD.getText().equals("Midday")){
            j = "12:00";
        }
        else if (ToD.getText().equals("Evening")){
            j = "5:00";
        }
        else {
            j = "10:00";
        }

        /*String l;

        if (wow.getText().equals("Weekend")){
           l="Sunday";
        }
        else {
            l="Wednesday";
        }*/

        TextView time = new TextView(this);

        time.setText( j + " " + s );

        return  time;

    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    pYear = year;
                    pMonth = monthOfYear;
                    pDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                    displayToast();
                }
            };

    public void updateDisplay() {
        pDisplayDate.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                        // Month is 0 based so add 1
                        .append(pMonth + 1).append("/")
                        .append(pDay).append("/")
                        .append(pYear).append(" "));
    }

    public void updateMainDisplay(){

        setMainText();

        top.setMText(MAINText);

    }

    /*public void updateTV(final String str1){
        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                context.getMainText().setText(str1);
            }
        });
    }*/

    public void displayToast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Date choosen is ").append(pDisplayDate.getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}



    /** Create a new dialog for date picker */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        pDateSetListener,
                        pYear, pMonth, pDay);
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_post, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void onCreateClick(View view){

        updateMainDisplay();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TopLevelActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


}
```

## Error Log Here:

```
 --------- beginning of crash
01-04 11:56:16.368    2057-2057/com.example.oife E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.oife, PID: 2057
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oife/com.example.oife.PostActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.oife.PostActivity> has no zero argument constructor
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.oife.PostActivity> has no zero argument constructor
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post your error log.

Comment: In the future, use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 1):

This is very wrong:

```
top = new TopLevelActivity();
```

you cannot create an activity instance to update it with some value, you must pass this value to your existing instance. To do this create new activity with startActivityForResult and receive it in TopLevelActivy.onActivityResult. For more read here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Also, get rid of the constructor on `PostActivity`, and get rid of `protected TopLevelActivity context;` from `PostActivity`.